# MS Access Query will not open in design mode

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently supporting a MS Access project, which has a lot of queries, designed in MS Access Query design. I want to open them to see the SQL. But every time I try to open them in Design view I am getting the following error:

> Invalid use of vertical bars in query expression.

Is there any way to open these queries? I need to do some enhancements in the project and for that I need to see the SQL behind these queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a saved query will not open in Design View, you can examine its `.SQL` property via the DAO object model.

Here is an example from the Access Immediate window which displays the SQL statement behind my saved query, *qryAddLogEntry*.  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you to the Immediate window.)

```vb
? CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryAddLogEntry").SQL
PARAMETERS some_text Text ( 255 );
INSERT INTO log_table ( log_text )
VALUES ([some_text]);
```

If necessary, you can also modify the query's SQL statement by changing that property.

```vb
strInsert = "PARAMETERS some_text Text ( 255 );" & vbCrLF & _
    "INSERT INTO log_table ( log_text, junk_field )" & vbCrLF & _
    "VALUES ( [some_text], 'Hello World');"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryAddLogEntry").SQL = strInsert
```